# How to push data from php to a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array variable and it will be used in a json. This is my code:

```
$arr = array();

    $data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_location WHERE loca_id = '$id' ")or die(mysql_error());
    while($a=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
           array_push(); //what should i do
    {
```

I want to push data from database to array like:

```
$arr= array(
    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "London",       
    )
);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: $a is already array I thnk? SO you could push it.

Comment: 1.) Stop using the mysql_* functions. Use [mysqli](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). 2.) Read the documentation for [array_push](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

Comment: yes but how to push to id and name

Comment: to patrick, i know i have to use mysqli, but this is urgent and my school still use mysql , sorry

Comment: @user3586378 what columm are in your database. Is it exactly 'id' and 'names'?

Comment: So this is a homework assignment?

Comment: @PoomrokcThe3years same like the example

Comment: @PatrickQ no this is our project, and my teacher just teach me mysql :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = array();

$data=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_location WHERE loca_id = '$id' ")or die(mysql_error());
while($a=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
       array_push($arr,$a);
{
```

Comment: @user3586378 : Have you succeeded?

Comment: yes but, how to push it to multidimension array

Comment: @user3586378 that's already multidimentional.

Comment: change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` and this is correct

Comment: oh god, i'm sorry @Notulysses this is my miss understand